# Redux persist always loads data when it is standalone for the first time

Tags: react-native, redux, expo, state, redux-persist

I'm new to react native, I'm developing with expo and I'm making my first app. I found a library called redux persist to be able to maintain the state of the application. The problem is when I compile the app it loads information that it shouldn't. Apparently this only happens on android.
What am I wrong?

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  request: requestReducer,
  profile: profileReducer,
  trip: tripReducer,
  agent: agentReducer,
  generalStatus: generalStatusReducer

});

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',  
  storage
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const store = createStore(persistedReducer, undefined, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

Comment: Ideally, Redux persist provides a way to blacklist a slice of data your app doesn't need to persist like loading states or frequently changed data.
https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#nested-persists